# Get Adwords approval for domain that contains some user generated pages of which Google disapproves

Tags: google-ads, landing-page

I have a site which let's people build a simple one page site (landing page) and host it on the site as a site page.

So if the main domain is domain.com a land page made by a user can be domain.com/4234

Now some people create landing pages that Google doesn't like (like those pages that mainly have a link to some other product page "affiliate", or pages that sell courses on how to make money and so...) and because of that Adwords marks the main site domain as disapproved.

Now of course I can't check every page that is made (thousands a month) to see if is matching Google policies and so...

How can I make Google approve or disapprove each page alone and not disapprove the all site because of some pages?

Comment: Please do not abuse the formatting tools. Thank you. :)

Comment: AdWords not AdSense?   As in your are buying ads on other sites that point to these pages created by others?   Why would you do that?

Comment: AdWords let you promote your site in the google search engine results (to be the first on the list) and i need it to bring clients to my site so they will create landing pages with my site (which is actually an online app).

Comment: I see, so you don't want to advertise to user generated content, just to the pages that promote your service.

Comment: Actually I want to be able to advertise the pages that promote my service, but I do also want my clients to be able to advertise there pages if they don't violate the Adwords policies (and not be effected by those who do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, talking with google again - they say if will have the landpages as subdomains they will be treated as separated sites and not effect each other.

This is a bit tricky to do, but it seems like it's the only practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look promising for you.   If your site has been suspended from Adwords, [Google says](https://support.google.com/adwordspolicy/answer/1704383?hl=en&ref_topic=1308266) that you must make changes to your site before you can appeal.   Furthermore, they even state:

> **Please note that not all policy violations are fixable.** We've carefully chosen the types of websites that we won't accept, in order to protect our users. If you're unable to fix your site or if you don't want to, we won't be able to run your ads for that site.

One possibility for you would be to move all the user-generated content to another domain.  Then you would only have content on your domain that you control.

Comment: That will (maybe) help for my main domain page but not for my clients with pages that don't violate the Adwords policies which will still be effected from the pages that do).

Comment: Maybe you could give each client a subdomain and have them apply with their subdomain only.

Comment: That could be working. ill just have to check how to do it :)